# Nonexisting field error while accessing user birthday in Facebook Android API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to access the user birthday & gender, but I am getting an error when I try to access the birthday.I am using the Facebook SDK version facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0.

It gives me this error:

> {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100)
>   Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday) on node type
>   (User)}}

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                                // Application code
                                String email = object.optString("email");
                                String birthday = object.optString("birthday");
                                String name = object.optString("name"); // 01/31/1980 format
                                info.setText("email:  " +
                                        email + "\n" +
                                        "birthday " + birthday+
                                "\n name"+name);
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,user_birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In the parameters you should use birthday instead of user-birthday:

```
parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, birthday");
```

See the documentation for available fields of user bio:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: still i can't get the birthdate{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"1710395395652830","name":"Avez Shaikh","gender":"male"}, error: null}

Comment: I had a look at this example ( http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.facebook.GraphRequest ) and it seems that everything should be fine. You are getting a 200 response and valid data which means that the request is ok. Is there a chance that the birthday data is not set in FB for your user?

Answer (score 3):

Some Facebook integrations require approval before public usage.

Without this you will received an ERROR message like this:

```
Facebook error: “(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday) on node type (User)”
```

Until reviewed and approved by Facebook, your app can use only the public user’s profile and email.

See next useful recommendations:

> Access to the date and month of birth of a person. Access to a
>   person's year of birth depends on their privacy settings and the
>   access token used to request this field.
>
> Please note that most integrations require only the age_range field.
>
> Check If an application requests this permission, Facebook specialists
>   should check how it will be used.
>
> When sending an application for review, you should specify exactly why
>   the age_range permission is not enough in this case.

Next links will be helpful for it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit